# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int.'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlclient

I have creates a database and I am trying to `INSERT INTO TABLE` with the following code:

```
string sqlquery = "INSERT INTO Runner VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @amount, @category, @city, @charity, @route)";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);

conn.Open();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtFirstName.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", txtLastName.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", Convert.ToInt32(txtMoney.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", cbBoxCategory.ValueMember);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", cbBoxCity.ValueMember);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@charity", cbBoxCharity.ValueMember);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@route", cbBoxRoute.ValueMember);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'id' to data type int.'

All my `cbBox` (comboBox) need to leave a `INT`, I understand that is need to convert to `NVARCHAR` to `INT`, I try to use `Convert.Into32(cbBox.Category.ValueMember)` but without success.

I have tried everything with no success.

Comment: The way you're doing your data access is very old.  Wouldn't you prefer something a bit more modern like Dapper or Entity Framework?

Comment: My guess is you have an `id` column in your table you're not setting. Specify your columns like `INSERT INTO Runner (firstName, lastName, amount, category, city, charity, route) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @amount, @category, @city, @charity, @route)` instead. Oh, and [Stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for other people answer I find this solution.

```
string sqlquery = "INSERT INTO Runner (firstName, lastName, amount, categoryID, cityID, charityID, routeID) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @amount, @category, @city, @charity, @route)";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
conn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =  txtFirstName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtLastName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@amount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtMoney.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cbBoxCategory.SelectedValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cbBoxCity.SelectedValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@charity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cbBoxCharity.SelectedValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@route", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cbBoxRoute.SelectedValue;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("New Runner has been registered!");
conn.Close();
```

By using `Convert.ToInt32(cbBoxRoute.SelectedValue)`

Here is the link where I find my solution:

[Insert ID into SQL from C# Combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293920/insert-id-into-sql-from-c-sharp-combo-box)

Comment: Seeing "SqlCommand" and "txtBox" and "cbCombobox" in the same code method.....I would strongly encourage you to do some basic layering of your code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures

Comment: I not doing web application, I using windows form
What you mean txtbox and cbCombobox?
Thanks for your tip, anyway! <3

Comment: The real problem is that you are using `AddWithValue` which guesses the best datatype and precision/scale to use for the parameter. You should not use `AddWithValue`, [ref 1](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [ref 2](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and instead build each SqlParameter manually, specifying the correct datatype, precision and scale to match your database.

Comment: And as a matter of best practice you should also list the columns you are inserting into your table e.g. `insert into Runner (FirstName, LastName, etc...) values (FirstName, LastName, etc...)`

Comment: Thanks you for the comment I appreciate and I will change my code!

Comment: @DaleK , I use the way you mention previous, and my code is more clean than never, thank you very much, for your tip and for the documentation.

Comment: You can still improve your code by setting the parameter size e.g. `Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 128)` (the size must match your column size). The reason for this is that when you leave it unset SQL Server generates a new query plan for every different sized input you use.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. Thanks!